# How can I configure openssl's default backend engine?

Tags: openssl, cryptography, backend

I compiled OpenSSL with cryptodev support (i.e. hardware acceleration), but unfortunately the default engine is still software.

```
time openssl speed -evp aes-128-cbc -engine cryptodev
```

yields the "right" number, but ProFTP (which also uses OpenSSL) does not show any performance gain when used (FTP Secure, FTPS, however you call it).

The engine has support for AES-128, AES-192, RC4, SHA-1, DES, Triple-DES and a few others.

My `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf` looks like this:

```
#...
# a lot of generic stuff...
#...

[engine_section]
cryptodev = cryptodev_section

[cryptodev_section]
default_algorithms = ALL
```

I looked into the code, but they do nasty things with defines, redefines, undefines, combined with prototypes which makes tracing a pain...

If the above is correct, what routine gets called to initialize the engines when the user creates CTX_SSL or similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [OpenSSL's config(5)](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/config.html): "The command default_algorithms sets the default algorithms an ENGINE will supply using the functions ENGINE_set_default_string()". I don't believe "ALL" is a valid engine. You might try specifying the `engine_id` to `default_algorithms`.

---

If you are doing this in source code, try calling:

```
ENGINE_load_builtin_engines();
```

followed by

```
ENGINE_register_all_complete();
```

If you have an `ENGINE*`, then you can do something like:

```
ENGINE* eng = ENGINE_by_id("XXX");
ENGINE_set_default(eng, ENGINE_METHOD_ALL);
OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
```

I'm not aware of any good documentation on the subject, but I have not checked Viega, Massier, and Chandra's book. A few of us were discussing it on an OpenSSL wiki talk page for [Libcrypto API](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Talk%3aLibcrypto_API).

Comment: I managed to fix it soley using the config, but I forgot to update this and I do not have access to the repo anymore which contains the config, anyways very good hint - old openssl versions seem to not have the `ENGINE_set_default_ciphers` (from http://forums.freebsd.org/showthread.php?t=7418 ).

Comment: There you can also see that `ALL` should be valid.